# Vintage LM317T Linear PSU Improvement Suggestions

Tags: power-supply, linear-regulator, reverse-engineering

Recently I came into possession of two very old linear PSU devices from 1993.

I replaced the caps and tested the devices and both work. I have been using them in conjunction with 12 7Ah lead acid batteries for powering my VHF radios.

Now I found some old transformers removed from the same devices and want to use them with the same circuit roughly...

I reversed the PSU and to the best of my ability it looks roughly like the picture below.

---

**Back of PCB with some symbols**

[image]

**Schematic I reversed**

[image]

My question is what improvements could I make to the design besides increasing the primary and secondary distance. I will be using the one I build for ham radios so I would like to keep the noise clean as practically possible.

Also I am not familiar with the type of choke used for AC filtering in this case. I  would greatly appreciate it if anyone knows the type and value of choke and is willing to share info on it.

---

**Front Secondary**

[image]

---

**Front Primary**

[image]

---

**~UPDATE~**

Schematic with suggestions

[image]

---

Comment: Nitpicking: Please draw R2, R3, R4 and VR1 pointing down in the future as they form a voltage divider.

Comment: @winny Thanks for the suggestion I have updated the schematic

Comment: _"very old"_ _"1993"_ Hey hey hey, take it easy with the old-shaming...

Comment: The fuse from +BATT connected to pin 2 doesn't make any sense. Are you sure it isn't connected to pin 3? Assuming this is your supply. LM317 TO220 viewed from the upside has 1=adj 2=Vout 3=Vin

Comment: @Jonas *Now I found some old transformers and want to use them with the same circuit roughly...* What old transformers? Please edit the question and say what secondary voltage rating the surplus transformers have. If it's too high, the 317 may be unable to dissipate the heat. A picture of each of the surplus transformers would help too.

Comment: @Lundin I just copied my first schematic from the PCB double checked with continuity and it is connected to the output pin so maybe it's just there to protect the battery from too much fast current draw or discharge.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica They are from the same ups devices but were removed by the previous owner, I got them for free at my ham club meeting and they are in good condition from what I was told. I don't know any of the transformer specs except for 16v out 230v in , and the markings _1RD 1212 20427600_ on the top of the transformers. will update the question as well.

Comment: @Jonas Or maybe you have gotten the LM317 pinning backwards/mirrored. Since it makes no sense in any situation to connect the output of a LM317 to a battery + pole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is no need to increase the transformer spacing.  The physical distance between the closest primary and secondary pins is way more than required for 240 Vac.
2. The value of RV1 is not given, but if it is adjusted down to 0 ohms, the output will be 15 V.  As it is right now, the schematic does not allow adjustability down to 1.25 V as indicated in the lower left corner.  That adjustment range is not a part of the original device.  Si it something you want to add to the original circuit as a modification?  If so, what is the desired output voltage range and maximum continuous output current?
3. Increase D3 to at least a 1N5401.  As a general rule for improved long-term reliability, run electronic components at 50% or less of their ratings.  35 V circuit = 60 V or 100 V diodes, same for transistors and caps.  Resistor power dissipation of 1 W = a 2 W part.  Etc.
4. Having the heatsink so close to the transformer has two potential issues.  a) the transformer is a source of heat, and is adding some of that heat to a part that is supposed to be cooling something else.  b) the right side of the heatsink is so close to the xfmr that air flow is restricted.
5. If you really want to draw 1 A or more when the output is adjusted down to something like 5 V, with 30 V -ish at the regulator input, that is not enough heatsink.
6. Consider replacing L1 and L2 with a common-mode choke designed for power line filter applications.
7. For better noise control, add 0.1 uF ceramic capacitors at the regulator input and output pins.
8. Just a comment - that is an awfully large transformer for a single LM317.  Do you know anything about its ratings?

UPDATE:

For a narrower adjustment range that gives you better adjustability (fewer volts per degree of rotation) centered about 13.8 V, try this:

R2 = 200

R3 = 1.8 K

R4 = 100

RV1 = 200

Vcenter = 13.75 V

A possible issue with this component set is that the adjustment range is around +/-4.5%, which is less than the tolerances of the fixed resistors.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I Just made the note 1.25v - 37v since the LM317 datasheet gave those options. I'd just use 13.8v really, maybe try adjustment voltage just for fun. RV1 looks like 470 ohms. Yeah the transformer Is massive I don't know any specs besides 16v out and the markings _1RD 1212 20427600_ on the top of the transformer. Will try your suggestions when I build mine.

Comment: A 16 V secondary is about 21 V into the regulator.  At 13.8 Vout and 1 A, that's about 7.2 W of heat in the 317 to be dissipated.  Without a front view of the heatsink it's hard to tell, but it looks a bit small for the job.

Comment: Delete R4 and change R3 to 1.6 K.  This should put 13.8 V near the center of the RV1 rotation.

Comment: See the UPDATE.

Comment: Thanks for your update. Will give the new components a try. Also looks like a bit of discoloration between the regulator and the transformer, I will definitely upgrade the current heatsinks and add some thermal compound.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the size of the transformer seems quite disproportionate to the size of the regulator and heatsink.

The biggest single improvement (depending on intended use) would be to increase the size of the heatsink and improve thermal bonding. You could even change to a TO3 package bolted to chassis somewhere, which would allow a much better heatsink. If you do this be sure to wire some 0.1uF ceramic decouplers right on the pins of the regulator for stability.

Like this you could probably increase current output. The maximum will vary a good bit with output voltage of course but it should be more.

Answer (score 1):

I think no other answer has touched the aspect of electrical safety and the obscurity of the circuit. I believe you did a good job reverse-engineering the schematics, with one missing but important detail (see below, but more important things first).

The PCB looks like it is not very safe, but I am not 100% sure.

First of all, the PCB has a three-pole inlet with Live/Phase, Neutral, and Earth/Ground.

And the second important point, missing from the schematics, is that the regulated DC output has the negative output (GND) terminal directly connected to Earth through the PCB, and the otherwise unused area of the PCB is flooded with copper plane connected to the Earth terminal, very close, if not too close to mains wiring.

The Earth connects to Live and Neutral via varistors.

This means that omitting the Earth connection by plugging it to non-earthed receptacle or otherwise faulty extension cord that leaves Earth disconnected, is a hazard.

Any overvoltage or leakage via Live wire (or Neutral wire, depending on which way the plug is plugged in if you have non-polar plugs) gets coupled to the Earth plane, and thus via GND output terminal to your equipment which you operate.

The fuse is also only protecting the transformer, but the varistors and inductors are on the unprotected side. So even if the fuse blows, mains can leak to touchable parts.

The distance between Live and Neutral to the Earthed copper plane that surrounds everything is very small, likely it would not pass modern safety requirements. Any moisture or dust in that small gap will cause more leakage to Earth, which I have to remind, is user touchable via the powered equipment.

As many older buildings have no Earth on the socket, I recommend never plugging this transformer into ungrounded socket, it just looks too dangerous.

So the TVS arrangement may not be the best idea, the fuse should be the first thing after the mains plug, not filters.

The Earth copper plane being so close to live parts also not a great idea.

The output being Earthed could be a good idea, but then, due to how the TVSes are connected, it might be safer to have the output isolated and floating instead of connected to Earth. Especially due to the TVS arrangement, this may be lethal when problems arise and there is a failure with the Earth connection via mains plug.

Then as for the device having an output and some battery feature, this makes little sense. The transformer and the regulator provide a DC voltage supply, and it is paralleled with a 12V battery, presumably car battery or similar lead-acid battery. The battery is separated from the battery only with a 4A fuse. A voltage regulator, or a constant voltage supply are not battery chargers. If the battery has only 11V, it forces the output to 11V, and the regulator tries to provide as much current it can to make the voltage rise to say the 12V adjustable setpoint, but it can't provide enough current to do that. Something has to give up. The regulator can't really provide more than 1-2A out, the battery can easily take or provide several amps if necessary, so likely fuse won't blow but regulator will likely heat up and go into thermal shutdown, which would limit the current, but it would be relying on the regulator safety feature which protects it from burning up in a puff of smoke.

There are battery charging circuits that are done with LM317, but this is not a battery charging circuit, just a constant voltage output regulator, trying to charge a battery, or rather just keep it topped off at float charge between bursts of high power usage (radio usage perhaps?).

So the LM317 likely runs very hot if the battery is not topped off, which also heats up the electrolytic capacitors, and they will degrade faster and have shorter usable life compared to a circuit running cooler.

The metal tab of the LM317 is also the output terminal, so any screw or heat sink making direct contact with it will have the output 12V on it. So for example it can't be connected to any metal such as the Earth copper plane, the transformer, or any metal case should the device have a metal case. If it does have a metal case, it should be connected to the Earth input. Not sure if insulated plastic enclosure would be a bit safer, in case of problems.

The LED is also driven on AC from transformer, not DC, so it will blink annoyingly at mains frequency. Fortunate consequence is that since it is not driven from the rectified side, it won't stay on or decay slowly when mains are unplugged, and due to the rectifier, there will be not much reverse bias voltage over the LED.

So all in all, the circuit is quite weird and not very safe. As for improving it, I suggest using it as a bad example and not using it as a base how to do things. You can buy safe and modern switch mode power supplies which also have proper built-in support for battery backup and charging, i.e. UPS support.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions the earth ground setup already had me worried and you have validated my concern. I really wanted to use these after refurbishment but it'll definitely be better just use a safer modern linear circuit with the existing transformers.

Answer (score 0):

That linear supply is just physically way too small for the job if all components are to fit on the PCB only. An LM317 can dissipate about 10W of heat while on an “infinite” heatsink. The puny heatsink on the PCB will have trouble with 1W - things will run hot and the component life will be shortened.

To keep the supply small, the LM317 would go onto a heatsink that’s a part of the enclosure.

The varistors to "protect" the primary don't do very much. The transformer's nonlinearities and time constants do enough to suppress transients that wouldn't destroy the varistors.